# Finding if a vertex is located between two edges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vertices

I have a data set of polygons which I want to convert to lines in order to measure the length of each line. However, some of the polygons have vertices which are located not in a corner of the shape. Is there a way to determine if a vertex sits in a corner or not? I've tried Dissolve or Simplify without success.

[image]

Comment: Simplify building https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00700000000z000000 or polygon https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Simplify_Polygon/007000000011000000/ or generalize tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m80000002n000000, the first uses an advanced license, the other two need standard or advanced license. Dissolve in this case wont do very much, it's more about merging adjacent or overlapping polygons. Which simplify method did you try and what parameters did you use?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson I don't remember which method I used, and it's become irrelevant to my task anyway (I was asked to keep the lines as they are). But I will try the the other GP tools and methods you suggested and see what it gets.

Comment: Try Integrate tool and see if it deletes intermediate vertices. Or Feature Vertices to Points, buffer points, erase with building, if whats left is 3/4 of original area its a corner point. Or Minimum Bound Geometry rectangle.

Comment: @BERA and CarmelGeo **Warning:** the integrate tool can *destroy* data if too high a tolerance is specified. It's one of the few tools that don't create an output modifying the input feature class instead, before using this tool **make a backup** as there is no *undo integrate*.